# Is there a way to set the Google Chrome's developer tools window to always be on top?

Tags: google-chrome, firebug

Is there a way to set the Google Chrome's developer tools window to always be on top after it's been detached from the Chrome window itself? If not, is there any way to set the Firebug Lite plugin for Chrome to "always on top"?
It would save the hassle of switching between windows when debugging.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're using Windows, [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/28907/make-window-always-on-top) answers it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! DeskPins works fine. Hopefully Google will add native support for this as well.

Comment: How about OS X??

Comment: @Matt, MacOS ??

Comment: You can also use Windows PowerToys

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Ubuntu Right Click Menu Bar and in Option Menu Click **Always on Top** ..

[Check Ask Ubuntu Answer Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/422874/how-do-i-keep-a-window-open-in-front-of-other-windows)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers didn't work for me, but a software called TurboTop did. Super simple.
https://www.savardsoftware.com/turbotop/download.asp

Btw google should add some feature to help with this.. I'm suprised more people don't complain.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline.